# Codacy does not show coverage using Travis-CI

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci, codacy

I'm trying to use travis-ci with Codacy, but travis is returning me the following error:

```
Please visit http://docs.codecov.io/docs/supported-languages
after_success.2
1.11s$ java -jar ~/codacy-coverage-reporter-assembly-latest.jar report -l Java -r build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
10/29 00:35:23 INFO  c.c.rules.ConfigurationRules:101 - Using API base URL: https://api.codacy.com 
10/29 00:35:23 ERROR c.c.CodacyCoverageReporter$:28 - File /home/travis/build/rjdesenvolvimento/apipessoas/build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml does not exist. 
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

My .travis.yml

```
dist: trusty
addons:
  sonarcloud:
    organization: "rjdesenvolvimento-github"
    token:
      secure: <token>
script:
- mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=rjdesenvolvimento_apipessoas -Dsonar.organization=rjdesenvolvimento-github -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io -Dsonar.login=51
after_success:
- bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
- java -jar ~/codacy-coverage-reporter-assembly-latest.jar report -l Java -r build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
```

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: it's the 3rd question you made with the same problem. Have you run the same steps that you are running in travis locally? Do you see the jacocoTestReport.xml file locally?

Comment: see for instance https://github.com/codacy/codacy-api-java/blob/master/circle.yml

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the Codacy support via the website? It seems that /home/travis/build/rjdesenvolvimento/apipessoas/build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml does not exist, how do you generate your coverage?

The Codacy plugin will only upload the coverage information, you still need to generate it.

Anyhow, contact the Codacy support and they will help you.